# movit_msgs error

Tags: ros, catkin-make, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was doing catkin_make on pr2_apps stack but i ran to this error,eventhough I have **moveit_msgs** installed in my system

/home/azar/catkin_ws/src/pr2_apps/pr2_teleop_general/src/pr2_teleop_general_commander.cpp:41:48: **fatal error: moveit_msgs/GetKinematicSolverInfo.h: No such file or directory**
#include <moveit_msgs/GetKinematicSolverInfo.h>
^
compilation terminated.

**can anybody help me??!!...**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224043/movit_msgs-error/) by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it all got fixed when i again run catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) with karma: 90 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0